# Fatal error: Call to a member function setTimerId() on boolean in ..\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\timer\index.phtml on line 1

Tags: magento-1.9

I have installed a module of timer on banner in Localhost. It shows this fatal error.

In index.phtml code is

```
<?php echo $this->getChild('leonambernini.timerbanner')->setTimerId()->toHtml(); ?>
```

[image: image description here]

Comment: Can you please give me module name. so i will check in details. its free ?

Comment: Timer Banner - Leonam Bernini

Comment: I add one frontend Module . Add PHP code in index.phtml of that module. Then call that phtml page on home page from backend.                          {{block type="timer/index" name="timer_index" template="timer/index.phtml"/}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call the banner is necessary to insert the call to the desired location below:

```
echo $this->getChild('leonambernini.timerbanner')->setTimerId('YOUR_BANNER_ID_SHOW')->toHtml()
```

Comment: Welcome in magento community ...

Comment: Ya Sir. I add one frontend module to insert PHP code ..

Comment: @Nikunj Patel +1 for you .